# Add an Enterprise Keyword query to Highlighted Content part

Tags: enterprise-keywords, highlighted-content-web-part

I'm new to Sharepoint Online. I'm trying to use the Highlighted Content part in order to serve up pages on the site that have the "Guidelines" tag on it.
[image: Pages with keywords]

When configuring the Highlighted Content part, I'm using the custom query `Keywords:"Guideline"`but it doesn't yield any results. Am I using this correctly? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Filters:
Filter: Managed Property
Managed Property Name: Tags
Contains
Full tag name